# How can fetch ManyToMany assosiation with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g, jpa-2.0

I'm developing a classic web application with `Spring`, `Hibernate`, `JPA 2.x` and `Oracle` as Database.
I have a `@ManyToMany` relationship and got an exception when i try to load it eagerly.
Demande.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DEMANDE_AUTORISATION")
public class DemandeAutorisationEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "VAR_ID", nullable = false)
    private VarianteEntity variante;
 ....
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "T_DEMANDE_QUESTION", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "DEMAUT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "DEMQUEST_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<VarQuestionEntity> varQuestions;

//Getters and Setters
```

Question.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_VAR_QUESTION")
@Immutable
public class VarQuestionEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "VAR_ID", nullable = false)
private VarianteEntity variante;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "varQuestions")
private Set<DemandeAutorisationEntity> demandeAutorisations;
//Getters and Setters
```

Query:

```
@Override
public List<DemandeAutorisationEntity> searchDemandes(DemandeAutorisationSearch search) {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.append("from DemandeAutorisationEntity demande ")
       .append(" INNER JOIN FETCH demande.varQuestions varQuestions");
     Query query = em.createQuery(sb.toString());

     return query.getResultList();
}
```

Both Demande and Question have `@ManyToOne` with `Variante`.
When i execute the query i got this exception :

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of fr.pasteur.gaip.dal.parameters.VarQuestionEntity was altered from 1 to null
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:67)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of fr.pasteur.gaip.dal.parameters.VarQuestionEntity was altered from 1 to null
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    ... 75 more
```

Comment: it seems has nothing to do with the query.  The exception happens when hibernate is committing txn (e.g. when closing session) and found ID of your entity altered.  Probably some logic in your retrievial code, or in the entity is doing such thing incorrectly.

Comment: The entities are generated by HibernateTools and i didn't add nothing inside, i also tried fetch = FetchType.EAGER but i got the same problem

Comment: as I said, it has nothing to do with the fetching.  Check in the stack trace and I believe you will find the exception was not originated from the line you do query.  It is when Hibernate is commiting the txn